# How use axios instance properties in vuex store?

Tags: vue.js, vuex

I have crate Axios Instance Properties in the main.js:

```
import Axios from "axios";

const axios = Axios.create({
  baseURL: process.env.VUE_APP_BASE_URL
})

Vue.prototype.$http = axios;
```

I can use it at the Vue instance, but how can I use it in the `store.js`, which is a `vuex` store?

`this.$http` cannot be found.

```
TypeError: _this.$http is not a function
```

---

I got the answer:

```
Use Vue.prototype.$http
```

Comment: TypeError: Cannot read property '$http' of undefined

Comment: the best answer to your question is not very clear. If your problem was solved with Cloud's answer, then please remove your own answer inside the question, otherwise add your own answer as an answer and accept it as the correct solution. Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can import `Vue` to use it.

```
import Vue from 'vue'

async action() {
  const response = Vue.http.get('api/users');
}
```

Comment: I'm trying to use an axios instance in my store.js. i have tried accessing the axios instance using Vue.$myInstance but i get undefined.I also tried this._vm.$myinstance but $myInstance is not a promise with this ome. I need help

Comment: Did you try access it without the $ sign?

Comment: Yes, and it returns undefined

Comment: Steps:
1. in `main.js/index.js`, `Vue.prototype.$http = axios`;
2. in `store.js`, access the `axios` instance using
```
import Vue from 'vue'

Vue.http.get('api/users');
```